# Extract raster value at each vertex from line, while keeping the line

Tags: qgis, dem, line, extract

So I have a line that is basically drawn from two points. A starting point and an end point. It looks like this:

[image]

I then **densify** the line by count and set the value to e.g. 50

[image]

Then I **explode** the line so that I get one feature (row) per vertex (I am not sure if that step is a good idea)

[image]

And then I do not know how to continue. My first Idea was to use the **profiles from lines** tool from SAGA. It does work and creates a point for each cell (actually the densifying might be unnecessary too) which holds the raster value. I also added the field `rn` for the row number.
[image]

However, when I then run the `points to path` tool, the height information gets lost.

Another idea was to simply use the `sample raster` tool for the exploded line. However, I cannot use the line as vector layer input for sampling the raster values.

Anybody has an idea on how I can output a line that for each vertex has the height information from the raster?

Comment: Would you like to add z value to the line's vertices or to get z values as a column? In your example, `points to path` tool makes a line from points, so you get one line (one row) and loose all table values for points. This is an expected result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using QGIS expressions, use this expression:

```
raster_value( 'DEM', 1, start_point($geometry))
```

This is to get the elevation from the raster called `DEM`, raster band `1` for the line's start point. To get the elevation of the line's end point, simply change `start_point` to `end_point`.

[image]

---

Variant:

If you want to calculate the elevation along a line with just two vertices at a regular interval, you can use the following expression that generates an array of elevation values - for each point on the line in a regular interval - an interval that can be defined on line 3 (here: `100`):

```
array_foreach(
    generate_series(
        0, length($geometry), 100  -- change interval here
    ),
    raster_value (
        'DEM',
        1,
        line_interpolate_point( 
            $geometry,
            @element
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: that is it! Thank you so much:):)

Answer (score 10):

You can use "Drape (set Z value from raster)" tool to set the z value of every vertex in the **densified** line to a value sampled from a raster.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah cool, did not know about this!:) Thanks a lot. But what I actually wanted was a column in the line-layer with all the z-values. Is that possible too?