# Getting the elevation around the boundary of polygon in QGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, vector

In QGIS 3.28.2 Firenze I'm working on developing a QGIS plugin to get the elevation along the boundary of a polygon.

Given a shapefile polygon and a raster, I've been able to think of one solution:

- Take the shapefile, shrink it by 0.95, get the difference (which is basically a thick boundary of the shapefile in polygon format, rather than line, and clip it to the raster to get a line of elevation.

What I'm looking for is a boundary of the shapefile, having the elevation data, as a raster.
In other words, a raster in the form of a boundary line of the shapefile. The original problem statement is, "Find the elevation along the boundary of a polygon".

[image: Shapefile after shrinking and using Difference tool with the original and the shrunk one]

[image: After clipping the difference shapefile with the raster]

Comment: Have you looked at the profile tool plugin to see how they do it and if you can adapt that code to use a polygon's exterior ring as input?

Comment: Get the boundary of the polygon, create points along this line in regular intervals (see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/458751/generating-points-along-line-with-specifying-the-origin-of-point-generation-in-q) and get the raster value for each point (see e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/454447/88814)

Comment: You could improve the likely answers by asking yourself what exactly you want as an end-product. Do you want a line "profile" representing the perimeter with elevations at per-determined distances along the perimeter (irrespective of direction), or do you want a polygon with elevation values at each node (essentially a 3-d polygon)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to make improvements to the approach you suggest above, you could do the following:

1. Convert the polygon to a line - use **Polygons to Lines** tool
2. Buffer the line (**Buffer** tool)
3. Clip the line using your original polygon (**Clip** tool)

[image]

You can then clip the elevation raster using this polygon, which should be a consistent width around the boundary.

Comment: Thank you, it worked as I wanted.